# wget: different speed in sudo and user mode

Tags: sudo, wget

If I execute `wget` from my terminal to download something, it realices multiple attempts to download it, and eventually it downloads it (or not!). For example, with three attempts and 10 seconds of wait, I get the next output:

```
$ LANG=C wget -T 10 -t 3 -O contents.txt www.google.com
--2013-04-14 14:55:48--  http://www.google.com/
Connecting to 213.181.73.145:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

--2013-04-14 14:55:59--  (try: 2)  http://www.google.com/
Connecting to 213.181.73.145:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

--2013-04-14 14:56:11--  (try: 3)  http://www.google.com/
Connecting to 213.181.73.145:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Giving up.
```

But if I execute the same line with `sudo`, the download works fine and immediately. Why is the reason?

Moreover, if I put a `wget` line inside a script, and this script is called from `cron`, also `wget` works fine.

**EDITED** It's an issue with a proxy. With: `wget --no-proxy` works also fine. How can I check which proxy are been using by the system? And why `sudo` ignore this proxy?

Comment: What happens if it does not download. Does it start at all? Do you get an error message? ....

Comment: Post edited with more information!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probable causes include:

- a custom `~/.wgetrc` in your `$USER` home directory. 
  Check `/etc/wgetrc` and `man wget(1)`
- `http_proxy` is set in any of your profile startup scripts

Comment: I haven't a local `wgetrc` file, and `/etc/wgetrc` is completely commented, except `passive_ftp = on`.

Comment: The power of simple hypotheses :-). +1

Comment: You're completely right: `env | grep "proxy"` prints `http://213.181.73.145:80` for both http and https. But I'm trying to discover where this proxy is setted, but I don't find anything.

Answer (score 2):

`213.181.73.145` is so not Google. It is a Spain address of the TELEJUMILLA PA block, which is not (as far as I know; I may be mistaken) affiliated with Google.

Try checking what IP you get when root.

(WAG: you're inside TeleJumilla, and ordinary users *ought to* get redirected to a proxy, which is not working, or is firewalled from the inside too).

Comment: You're right. IP's are differents. How and/or where can I check or see which DNS server are `wget` asking, or how can I force `wget` to use an specific DNS server?

Comment: You can try asking a nonexistent host and checking both output and error message. This ought to work in most distros: `host -vvv domainthatdoesnotexist.org`. See also updated answer: you can check the `iptables` configuration.

Comment: I have edited the post. It's a problem with proxies.

Comment: Ah, I'm *a fool*. That was **not** `wget` trying to connect to Google, it's simply `wget` trying to connect with *the proxy*. I have a different version of `wget` and it fooled me. The correct answer was @dawud's (option 2), and you ought to check your user's login scripts.